# SF Symbol unavailable warning when using an SVG

Tags: ios, xcode, svg, compiler-warnings, sf-symbols

My app supports iOS 13.0 and uses SF Symbols in a storyboard. I have added the SF Symbol `.svg` file to my asset catalog to add support for those that are only available in iOS 14+ but I am still getting the compiler warnings saying

> SF Symbol 'square.and.arrow.up' is unavailable prior to iOS 14.0. Add
> a fallback image of the same name to the asses catalog for backward
> deployment

I have confirmed the symbols work on iOS 13.

If I click on one of the warnings, it takes me to the storyboard and the warning goes away. As soon as I navigate to another file, the warnings reappear.

Is there a way to get rid of these or could this be an Xcode bug?

Comment: It could *probably* be classified as an Xcode bug... but, which way is the "bug"? Since it is only a warning, not an error, should it *always* be there or *never* be there?

Comment: I'd say that once you do what it says and add a custom one to the project, the warning is no longer needed. I like to clear all my warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this.
Rename the `.svg` in the asset catalog to something different (I just added `X-` to the beginning), then change the image used in the storyboard to the new `X-` one.
It's the same `SF Symbol` and works exactly the same for iOS 13+ but because it's not the system build in one, the warnings go away :)